# Get all users from Google domain. Google Admin SDK - Users List

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-admin-sdk

I want call this api https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users.

I Have an application from Google Console with creditendials configured. API KEY.

I'am admin of my google gsuite domain.

I call

https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=xxx-xxx.com&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

And I have this message

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "required",
                "message": "Login Required",
                "locationType": "header",
                "location": "Authorization"
            }
        ],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Login Required"
    }
}
```

I do not understand how it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting all users from G suite is very simple. You have code for list the users from Gsuite in [this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/get-start/getting-started) webpage. Choose your language you are working now on the left side panel. Follow the guide properly. No need to change a single line of code. I have listed all the users from G suite by following java Quickstart.

You can try this also -

- You can use Google API Explorer
- Go to [this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) webpage
- You can find "Try this API" iframe or just press "Try it" button on the right-side panel
- Refer the page and provide the parameter required.
- Just provide your domain and orderBy as parameters.
- It will open a new window and asked for authentication & authorization
- Once you complete the authorization, users in your Gsuite will be displayed in JSON format.

Comment: Copy the pertinent information into this article, so that in the future when the link changes this answer is still useful

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion J. Murray. I will edit my answer